# detecting nodes in xml

Tags: php, xml, xpath

for example, we have this xml:

```
<p>[TAG]
    <span>foo 1</span>
    <span>foo 2</span>
   [/TAG]
    <span>bar 1</span>
    <span>bar 2</span>
</p>
```

how can i detect `<span>`-tags between words `[TAG]` and `[/TAG]` ("foo 1" and "foo 2" in this case)?

**UPD.** for example i need to change nodeValue of each span between `[TAG]` and `[/TAG]`

Comment: What do you mean by "detect"?

Comment: for example i need to change nodeValue of each span between `[TAG]` and `[/TAG]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you only have one set of `[TAG]..[/TAG]` per node (as in, if your document has two sets they're within separate `<p>` elements or whatever), and that they're always siblings:

You can use `preceding-sibling` and `following-sibling` to select only elements which are preceded by a [TAG] text node and followed by a [/TAG] text node:

```
//span[preceding-sibling::text()[normalize-space(.) = "[TAG]"]][following-sibling::text()[normalize-space(.) = "[/TAG]"]]
```

A full PHP example:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile('test.xml');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

foreach ($xpath->query('//span[preceding-sibling::text()[normalize-space(.) = "[TAG]"]][following-sibling::text()[normalize-space(.) = "[/TAG]"]]') as $el) {
 $el->nodeValue = 'Changed!';
}

echo $doc->saveXML();
```

Comment: this `<p>[TAG] <span>foo 1</span> <span>[/TAG]</span></p>` and this `<p> <span>[TAG]</span> <span>foo 1</span>[/TAG]</p>` xml's can't be parsed only by xpath-query, right?

Comment: @cru3l - Sure can. Just get rid of the `-sibling` in `preceding-sibling` and `following-sibling`.

Comment: @Dimitre But in all the given examples the "tags" inhabit their own text nodes, so we can quite happily use them in XPath queries

Comment: @Chris-Smith: Not at all. If you look closely at the first comment by @cru3l above you'll see: `<p>[TAG] <span>foo 1</span> <span>[/TAG]`. As you can see, the last tag within is an unclosed `<span>`. This is not possible to "select" eith XPath.